# Süddeutsche Füllwörter: "Fei"

Tags: etymology, dialect

Ich suche nach Herkunft und (möglicherweise) früherer Bedeutung der Füllwörter "fei", die es im bayrischen und schwäbischen Dialekt - und möglicherweise noch in anderen - gibt.

"Sie, dös is *fei* mei Einkaufswagn"

"Sie, des isch *fei* verbota"

(Ich glaube, das österreichische "eh" ist sehr ähnlich und tippe ein bisschen in diese Richtung)

Es wäre irgendwie naheliegend, auf den Wortstamm "fein" zu kommen, bloss will mir das nicht recht einleuchten. Ausser *übrigens* fällt mir auch kein direktes hochdeutsches Äquivalent ein - das im Übrigen meinem Gefühl nach auch nicht ganz dasselbe bedeutet. Zu irgendwas müssen die häufig verwendeten Füllsel ja mal gut gewesen sein.

Comment: Interessant, dass es das im Süddeutschen gibt! In der Schweiz existiert das gleiche Wort in ähnlicher Bedeutung im [Berndeutschen](http://www.edimuster.ch/baernduetsch/woerterbuechli.htm) aber meines Wissens nicht in anderen Dialekten.

Comment: Auch das ist interessant - vor allem, weil es allein aufgrund der Geographie die Vermutung der Herkunft aus dem Französischen (siehe Antwort unten) stützt. Allerdings habe ich anhand des verlinkten "Wörterbuchs" ein bisschen meine Zweifel, ob die Verwendung wirklich deckungsgleich ist.

Comment: Ich habe eine bessere Herleitung gefunden, siehe Antwort unten.

Comment: also ich hätte das als Schwabe ja "veih" geschrieben...

Comment: F liegt mir irgendwie näher. Aber ich gestehe, ich hab' vorher nachgeguckt ;)

Comment: *Dös* ist Ostbairisch; bei mir hieße der Satz »Sie, des is fei mei Eikafswong« ;)

Comment: Erinnert mich im Klang und Verwendung an das kärntnerische "lei". Zb "Kanns lei net sogn".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fei) enstammt *fei* dem französichen *fin* (**endlich**; **gänzlich**). Es entspricht im Hochdeutschen vielen verschiedenen Füllwörtern wie ***aber***, ***bloß***, ***endlich***, ***wohl***. Auch dein ***übrigens*** ließe sich wohl (bzw. *fei*) für deinen ersten Beispielsatz angeben. Es scheint, dass *fei* einfach nur ein Art Universal-Füllwort ist, um einer Aussage Nachdruck zu verleihen bzw. etwas zu betonen.

> "Sie, dös is *fei* mei Einkaufswagn"
>
> "Sie, das ist **aber**/**übrigens** mein Einkaufswagen!"

---

> "Sie, des isch *fei* verbota"
>
> "Sie, das ist **aber** verboten!"

Um zu der Etymologie zurückzukehren, könnte man das auch mit **gänzlich** ausdrücken, klingt aber eher komisch:

> "Sie das ist (aber) **gänzlich** verboten.

Comment: Im Vergleich zu 'Das ist verboten!' klingt die Version mit 'fei' für mich eher abgeschwächt, nicht betont.

Comment: Ich stimme der Erklärung in der Antwort zu, finde aber, dass die Ersatzfüllwörter die Bedeutung (zumindest im Schwäbischen) eher nicht wiedergeben. Keines der Wörter wie *gänzlich*, *aber* oder *übrigens* trägt die "Dringlichkeit" der Aussage und die implizierten Konsequenzen der kommentierten Aktion in sich, die meines Erachtens mit *fei* ausgedrückt werden. "Des isch fei verbota" ist eben nicht einfach nur eine "neutrale" Information, dass etwas komplett verboten ist, sondern verstärkt die Aussage zu einer dringenden Warnung an den Angesprochenen.

Comment: In den drei Buchstaben schwingt ganz schön viel mit - in meinem schwäbischen Beispiel von oben (ich denke, ich kann das beurteilen, ist immerhin meine "Muttersprache") z.B. auch ein Unterton von "eigentlich würde ich ja gar nicht mit Ihnen reden, weil ich Sie nicht kenne, da Sie aber gegen ein Verbot verstoßen, nehme ich mir das heraus" und fast immer die "Vertretung einer höheren Autorität". Eine Abschwächung ist es allerdings nicht. Die hochdeutschen Partikel geben das mMn nicht wieder.

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe bezüglich der schweizer Variante Interessantes im Idiotikon (einem sehr detaillierten Schweizer Wörterbuch) gefunden:

- *fei* verweist auf [fin](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id1.htm#!page/10835/mode/1up), d.h. "fein" in schweizerdeutscher Aussprache.
- Und im Eintrag zu *fin* heisst es

> II. Adv[erb] in abstr[aktem] S[inn] mit verstärkender Bedeutung, vor Adj. und Verben; oft aber nur, um der ganzen Rede oder einem Teil derselben einen leisen Nachdruck zu geben

Es kann also sein, dass die Ableitung von französischen *fin* and und für sich stimmt, aber auf den falschen Wortsinn verweist: Als Adjektiv bedeutet *fin* **fein**. Dann ist es aber natürlich plausibler, dass, *fei* direkt von *fein* abgeleitet ist.

Die Beispiele, die zu dieser Konstruktion im Idiotikon zitiert werden, sind der süddeutschen Konstruktion sehr ähnlich, z.B. (übersetzt): "Du machst mir *fei* Angst", "Ist es nicht *fei* eine Schande"

Comment: Mindestens im Züricher Raum würde hier allerdings "im fall" verwendet.

Comment: @Burki: Huch! Kannst du das mal bebeispielen? Das klemmt bei mir irgendwie.

Comment: "Sie, das ist im Fall mein Einkaufswagen". Wie @Burki sagt, sehr gebräuchlich bei Zürchern. Deutlich aggressiver als *fei*.

Comment: @tofro man kann "im Fall" auch als Verstärkung anhängen: "ich han im Fall hunger", oder "ich han hunger, im Fall" (mit beliebig vielen Ausrufezeichen, je nach persönlichen Vorlieben  :-)